# Having trouble with OUTPUT paramaters in SP with sqlsrv (PHP)

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, output-parameter

Sorry for my poor english. Here's the problem: i'm trying to reciebe an ID in PHP from a table in sql server express 2014 via sqlsrv driver, an SP and a output parameter.

When i execute de SP and print the output parameter via SSMS everything works just fine. However, when i call the SP from PHP the SP is executed but the output parameter doesn't change.

This is the SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SiguientePaciente](
    @IdExamen int OUTPUT
) AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SET @IdExamen = (SELECT TOP 1 T.IdExamen FROM TURNOS T WHERE T.Estado = 0 ORDER BY T.FechaHora ASC)

    UPDATE TURNOS SET Estado = 1 WHERE IdExamen = @IdExamen

    RETURN
END
```

This is the PHP, assume that `$conexion` works:

```
$idExamen = 0;
$sql = "{CALL SiguientePaciente (?)}";
$params = [&$idExamen, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_INT, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_INT];
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $sql, $params);
if($stmt !== false){
    //sqlsrv_next_result($stmt);
    echo $idExamen;
}
else
    echo print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
```

In the end, `echo $idExamen` prints `0`

---

EDIT: found an alternative way to do what i want, with a SELECT inside the SP. Then i just fetch de result in PHP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SiguientePaciente](
    @IdExamen int OUTPUT
) AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SET @IdExamen = (SELECT TOP 1 T.IdExamen FROM TURNOS T WHERE T.Estado = 0 ORDER BY T.FechaHora ASC)

    UPDATE TURNOS SET Estado = 1 WHERE IdExamen = @IdExamen

    SELECT @IdExamen AS IdExamen
    RETURN;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

At this [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc626303(v=sql.105).aspx) there is another way to assign your php `$params` array. I try to adapt that form to your case:

```
$params = array(   
                 array($idExamen, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)  
               );
```

It seems that doesn't need to apply referencing operator (I think) to the output variable when passing it, and other php constants related to the parameter..

**update after comment**

try also

```
SELECT TOP 1 @IdExamen = T.IdExamen FROM TURNOS T WHERE T.Estado = 0 ORDER BY T.FechaHora ASC
```

it is a bit more compact..

Comment: uhm, strange, i think i read somewhere about using the `&`. I just tried what you are saying and nothing. I managed to do this by putting a SELECT clause in the SP and fetching the result. However that's just an alternative way and therefore not the answer

Comment: @NicolasPaz at this point, try to assign "@idExamen" in the first query so it is a bit more compact.. see my post updated